# Установка Three.js на локальный сервер

Tags: three.js

Подскажите как я могу установить **Three.js** на локальный сервер, мне нужен только главный файл и *OBJLoader.js*, но когда я устанавливаю эти файлы выдается, ошибка, что не так?

И также если скачивать, то только полный репозиторий с github на 2 гб?

Установка с https://threejs.org/ Закачивает **three.js-master.zip**, который не хочет распаковываться, что не так?

(Я использую локальный сервер xampp)

Comment: Не совсем ясно какую проблему вы хотите решить. Three.js - WebGL библиотека. То есть, библиотека JS для более высокоуровневого доступа к WebGL -> OpenGL ES 2.0 в браузере и работе с видеокартой. Даже при установленном Nodejs на сервере у вас нет доступа к браузерным API, отвечающим за взаимодействие с отображением и работой с видеоускорителем, которого, как я понимаю, тоже нет на сервере. Вы собственно чего добиваетесь установкой браузерной библиотеки на сервере?

Comment: Никакой установки там нет, на Гите это сама Мастер-ветка для разработчиков библиотеки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Недавно так же столкнулся с этой проблемой.

1. Скачать 9 либ:

   CurveExtras.js
   FBXLoader.js
   fflate.module.js
   NURBSCurve.js
   NURBSSurface.js
   NURBSUtils.js
   OrbitControls.js
   three.js
   three.module.js
2. Импортировать в основном файле 3 из них (остальные участвуют в зависимостях уже внутри их)

   import * as THREE from './js/three.module.js';

   import { OrbitControls } from './js/OrbitControls.js';

   import { FBXLoader } from './js/FBXLoader.js';
3. Дальше пойдут ошибки, связанные с зависимостями скачанных либ, которые нужно исправлять по мере поступления. Все они связаны с импортом в самом начале файла, от вас требуется просто правильно указать пути в каждой из либ
   Пример:

import {
Vector4
} from './three.module.js';

import * as NURBSUtils from './NURBSUtils.js';